# Cover area with point clusters bounds

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, aggregation, concave-hull

Suppose, I have an area covered with regular grid points.
[image]

Points have some categorial attribute. I need to cover the area with polygons corresponding to the value of this attribute (it is like bounds of clusters). I have tried following methods

- Converted grid to rectangles and dissolved by attribute values.
- Minimum bounding geometry and convex hulls (but they are relevant for convex polygons)
- Concave hull (but I am getting empty space between hulls)

I want to get polygons like on pic below - smooth and adjacent to each other
[image]

Are there any alternatives to these methods.

Comment: Do you have the outer boundary as a polygon layer?

Comment: @BERA If you mean the area, which is covered by points - yes it is one polygon

Comment: What is the problem with "Converted grid to rectangles and dissolved by attribute values."? What does not work? Did you have a look at voronoi polygons?

Comment: @Babel
Converted grid to rectangles and dissolved by attribute values." - areas are not smooth
Voronoi polygons - since my points are regular, I am getting equal squares, which is the same as using rectangles grid

Comment: So OK, than use voronoi polygons to dissolve - you might also use aggregate tool